# selenium web driver - switch to parent window

Tags: java, selenium, window, webdriver, switch-statement

I use selenium Web Driver. I have opened a parent window. After I click on the link the new window opens. I choose some value from the list and this window automatically closes. Now I need to operate in my parent window. How can I do this? I tried the following code:

```
String HandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).click();
 for (String Handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(Handle);}
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("...")).click();
 driver.switchTo().window(HandleBefore);
```

This does not work though.

Comment: you iterate over your open windows switching to everyone and at the end you go on with the last in the list.... what's that for?

Comment: i just don't know another way switch to child window. It works for me, but i couldn't switch back to parent

Answer (score 1):

Try this before you click the link that opens the new window:

```
parent_h = browser.current_window
# click on the link that opens a new window
handles = browser.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
handles.remove(parent_h)
browser.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
# do stuff in the popup
# popup window closes
browser.switch_to_window(parent_h)
# and you're back
```

Comment: i know this is in python... but you can just translate the methods into java

Answer (score 0):

public boolean switchBackParentWindowTitle(String windowTitle){

```
    boolean executedActionStatus = false;
    try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> handles = null;

        handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){

            String switchWin = it.next();
            popup = driver.switchTo().window(switchWin);

            System.out.println(popup.getTitle());
            if(popup.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(windowTitle)){

                log.info("Current switched window title is "+popup.getTitle());
                log.info("Time taken to switch window is "+sw.elapsedTime());
                executedActionStatus = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                log.info("WindowTitle does not found to switch over");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Ex: "+er);
    }   
    return executedActionStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not answer your question, however it might answer a similar one. 
With `SeleniumBase` all you need to do is write:

```
self.switch_to_default_window()
```

And you're back to the parent window.

Comment: Thanks for contributing on stackoverflow! Answer section is only to share answers to the question please do not post statements that do not answer the exact question in the answer section.