# Couple Things With Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been doing some work with Selenium and Fiverr.com and I've run into some issues I was hoping to get some help on. I'm trying to create a new gig, and I've managed to do everything but a few things still are stumping me. One thing is the picture uploading.

• You have a button that you click a file input type () that brings up a Windows dialog, my plan thus far to use `SendKeys.SendWait` has worked, except for the part where you push "Open" on the Windows dialog to submit the picture. I've tried using SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}") to click it but that hasn't worked for me so far, so any ideas on that? I can't think of any other way to do it unless P/Invoke has something to handle Windows Dialog boxes?

•I'm also trying to enter text into the 'Description' box, and haven't been able to do that yet. I have tried to get it by class name, but it tells me that it can't access the class because it is hidden, have also tried to do it through Javascript (`IJavaScriptExecutor`) like so:

```
    IWebElement detailFrame = firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body"));
    var executor = firefoxDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'hiiiiiiii'", detailFrame);
```

It's odd because they're using body for the text field like so:

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" spellcheck="true" class="wysihtml5-editor" contenteditable="true" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119); cursor: auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">TEXT HERE<span id="_wysihtml5-undo" class="_wysihtml5-temp"></span></body>
```

I think they're using two different 'bodys' though, but the XPath just shows that it's /html/body. How would I set the text for something like this?

Thank you guys for your help, been at this for the past two hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Selenium has mechanism for handling window. You can use `driver.SwitchTo().Window("");` to set focus on newly opened window and perform additional action on it. However, keep that in mind to go back to parent window you may need to use *default content* again. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359118/selenium-web-driver-switch-to-parent-window) for other window handling techniques.
2. First of all, selenium doesn't recognize hidden element. If you know for sure the element is not hidden then I might say taht the selector you are using probably not correct. If I understand the html you provided clearly and the element is visible then I suggest you use xpath for that element. `//*[@id='_wysihtml5-undo']//..` can be helpful one for you

Comment: Tells me unable to locate the element (the _wysihtml5-undo), I've tried by XPath as well as by ID, any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly the steps you are trying to do?

Comment: firefoxDriver.FindElementById("_wysihtml5-undo").SendKeys("Hi");
or
 firefoxDriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='_wysihtml5-undo']").SendKeys("Hi");

Both throw the same error that it's not found.

Comment: Ended Up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048742/using-c-sharp-with-selenium-and-cleditor

Comment: You never mentioned iframe. So I automatically thought you are dealing with Newly opened window. Glad SO helped

Comment: Still trouble on clicking the "Open" button on the dialog though :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66702/discussion-between-saifur-and-frank).