# Closing new window in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

I have written the following code to open a google map window get it's url then close it and perform the actions on my previous window:

```
        try 
          {

           String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
            element("icon_google_map").click();
            for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
             {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
             }
           Thread.sleep(9000);
            String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            logMessage(currentURL);
            String expectedURL="xyz";
            Assert.assertEquals(currentURL, expectedURL);
            logMessage(currentURL);
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
            return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

The code above opens the map window but does not close it,instead it shows the following error when i perform the action on previous window.

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed

Comment: possible duplicate of [selenium web driver - switch to parent window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359118/selenium-web-driver-switch-to-parent-window)

Answer (score 0):

you are closing the driver before switching so selenium can't find the window.

do switching first then close the driver.

driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

driver.close();

Comment: Won't switching before closing,would close the parent window?

Comment: can just increase the wait time and see what happen ?

Comment: actually the problem is with google window ,the handle is changing but it is not getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below line of code

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
             {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
             }
```

You are not switching to right window.
You can do so by switching to second window like this.

```
driver.switchTo().window(getWindowHandles()[1]);
```

Comment: I am successfully switching to correct window the only problem is the new google map  window is not closing .

Comment: if i am not wrong, then in your case, the parent window is getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will switch the new window and will also the Google MAP window

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
             {
               driver.switchTo().window(getWindowHandles()[1]);
               driver.close();  // This will close the new open window
             }
```